# ENVI to map composition

Tags: envi

I'd like to print out 6 images in a single page. How can I do this using map composition tools in ENVI (6 images are year-to-year dynamic images  with the same size and the same geo-referencing)?

Comment: I would avoid any cartography whatsoever in ENVI and opt for a GIS such as ArcGIS or QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a direct answer but this is what I did when I had the same requirement - six temporal images had to come in one page. I had around 30 then.

I exported every image as high quality PNG images and later pasted them onto LibreOffice (you can paste them onto MS Word or any word processor) document - six per page and printed it.

I was using GRASS GIS and Quantum GIS then.

Answer (score -1):

This is not directly possible in ENVI, at least by using basic functionalities. Best way to do this is export per year image in a high resolution and 
(i) [subplot using matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/recipes/create_subplots.html) on python and save as png or
(ii) use microsoft office powerpoint or Adobe Illustrator to locate images manually  in a single page and export this as png.

Comment: The OP was not asking about mosaicking.  They want to print 6 images of the same location on one page to show changes over the years.

Comment: Mosaicking can stitch together neighboring images, but is not applicable (and maybe not even possible) when the images are co-located ("year-to-year dynamic images with ... **the same geo-referencing**").

Comment: I updated my answer.